# Probability of Sampling All Members of a Subset At Least Once with Repeated, Without-Replacement Sampling

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, coupon-collector

Given a set containing *n* unique members, what are the odds that all members of a subset *m* are sampled at least once when non-replacement samplings of size *k* are repeated *i* times? Members are replaced between samplings.

Using the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient), we can figure out the probability that a single member of the subset is never sampled in the *i* samplings. With that probability and the [complement rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_event), we can find the probability that a single member of *m* is sampled at-least once in the *i* samplings. However, I am struggling to find a way to represent the probability of sampling **each** of the members of *m* at least once.

I know that it's not the complement of the probability of sampling *m* raised to *i* because the members of *m* could be spread out across multiple sampling events and still be represneted.

Examples:

n = {1,2,3,4,5},
m = {1,2},
k = 3,
i = 2,

"Good":
({1,3,5}, {2,4,5}) - 1 and 2 sampled (different samplings)

"Good":
({1,2,3}, {3,4,5}) - 1 and 2 sampled (same sampling)

"Bad":
({3,4,5}, {3,4,5}) - neither 1 nor 2 sampled

"Bad":
({1,3,4}, {1,4,5}) - 2 never sampled

Comment: If we are sampling without replacement, it is not possible to sample any item more than once.  So why do the phrases "no replacement" and "sampled at least once" both appear in the first sentence?

Comment: I think "no-replacement" refers only to the individual samplings of size $k$, i.e. $k$ items are sampled without replacement and then all $k$ are replaced and the process is repeated $i$ times? Could you confirm that and clarify the question accordingly? It's hard to understand and easy to misunderstand as currently formulated.

Comment: Michael, apologies for the unclear question. joriki was correct in their interpretation. I've never heard of the coupon collector problem and seems like the right framework to find my answer. Thank you all!